# the behavior of std::async with std::launch::async policy

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have some question about behavior of `std::async` function with `std::launch::async` policy & `std::future` object returned from async.

In following code, main thread waits for the completion of `foo()` on the thread created by `async` call.

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
  std::cout << "foo:begin" << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
  std::cout << "foo:done" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "main:begin" << std::endl;
  {
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, foo);
    // dtor f::~f blocks until completion of foo()... why??
  }
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
  std::cout << "main:done" << std::endl;
}
```

And I know http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/future/async.html says

> The destructor of the last future object associated with the
>   asynchronous state of the returned std::future shall block until the
>   future is ready.

My question is:

- Q1. Does this behavior conform to the current C++ standard?
- Q2. If Q1's answer is yes, which statements say that?

Comment: What's so amazing about the standard is that often one footnote completely changes a chapter...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this is required by the C++ Standard. 30.6.8 [futures.async] paragraph 5, final bullet:

> — the associated thread completion synchronizes with (1.10) the return from the first function that successfully detects the ready status of the shared state or with the return from the last function that releases the shared state, whichever happens first.

The destructor of the one and only `std:future` satisfies that condition, and so has to wait for the completion of the thread.

Comment: OP's code does NOT work the same for VS2012. It doesn't block on `future` destructor. Is it some kind of bug, or the Microsoft simply accepted the Sutter's proposal not to block in dtors?

Comment: Microsoft chose to implement Herb Sutter's proposal to not block in destructors.

Comment: This behaviour is a big problem, but I fear it's too late now to fix the Standard. Microsoft chosing to implement non-standard behaviour because they don't agree with it just make life difficult for cross platform developers.

Comment: At the C++ Standards Committee meeting this week we are actively discussing a proposal to change the standard. The code above will still work (because it uses `auto`), but `std::async` won't return a `std::future` any more --- it will instead return a `std::waiting_future`. Herb has said that Microsoft will change their code to whatever is decided this week (even if that's the status quo).