# Safe multi-thread counter increment

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, boost, boost-thread

For example, I've got a some work that is computed simultaneously by multiple threads.

For demonstration purposes the work is performed inside a while loop. In a single iteration each thread performs its own portion of the work, before the next iteration begins a counter should be incremented once.

My problem is that the counter is updated by each thread.

As this seems like a relatively simple thing to want to do, I presume there is a 'best practice' or common way to go about it?

Here is some sample code to illustrate the issue and help the discussion along. 
(Im using boost threads)

```
class someTask {
public:
    int mCounter; //initialized to 0
    int mTotal; //initialized to i.e. 100000
    boost::mutex cntmutex;                
    int getCount()
    {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( cntmutex );
            return mCount;
    }
    void process( int thread_id, int numThreads )
    {
        while ( getCount() < mTotal )
        {
            // The main task is performed here and is divided 
            // into sub-tasks based on the thread_id and numThreads

                            // Wait for all thread to get to this point

            cntmutex.lock();
            mCounter++;  // < ---- how to ensure this is only updated once?
            cntmutex.unlock();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: There is more than that: is it necessary that the threads wait for each other ? Could you not have a designated *master* thread ? Or perhaps a scheduler that would do nothing but wait ?

Comment: @MatthieuM ah yes, waiting is important all threads must complete their work for the iteration before the increment is performed, i'll add it.

Comment: Your edit is erroneous: you need to use the same lock for all accesses to a given set of variables. Therefore you only need one lock here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem I see here is that you reason at a too-low level. Therefore, I am going to present an alternative solution based on the new C++11 thread API.

The main idea is that you essentially have a schedule -> dispatch -> do -> collect -> loop routine. In your example you try to reason about all this within the `do` phase which is quite hard. Your pattern can be much more easily expressed using the opposite approach.

First we isolate the work to be done in its own routine:

```
void process_thread(size_t id, size_t numThreads) {
    // do something
}
```

Now, we can easily invoke this routine:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void process(size_t const total, size_t const numThreads) {
    for (size_t count = 0; count != total; ++count) {
         std::vector< std::future<void> > results;

         // Create all threads, launch the work!
         for (size_t id = 0; id != numThreads; ++id) {
             results.push_back(std::async(process_thread, id, numThreads));
         }

         // The destruction of `std::future`
         // requires waiting for the task to complete (*)
    }
}
```

(*) See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733432/the-behavior-of-stdasync-with-stdlaunchasync-policy).

You can read more about `std::async` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), and a short introduction is [offered here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-8-futures-and-promises.html) (they appear to be somewhat contradictory on the effect of the launch policy, oh well). It is simpler here to let the implementation decides whether or not to create OS threads: it can adapt depending on the number of available cores.

Note how the code is simplified by *removing* shared state. Because the threads share nothing, we no longer have to worry about synchronization explicitly!

Comment: This looks like perfectly good solution to the question I posted. (I have to say though I prefer low level solutions, simply because I know exactly what is going on.) Though i'm not sure what 'result' is being pushed into the result vector?

Comment: On the other hand this is not what I want because the task is creating threads, whereas I have a finite thread pool that processes tasks until all tasks in a queue are complete, when there are no tasks they wait for one. Some tasks are specified to be performed by one thread, some tasks are performed by multiple threads. hope that made sense.

Comment: @AlexS: The idea of the `vector` is just to store the `future` (using move construction) so that its destruction is delayed. This let us create several concurrent tasks, that may start running in parallel. Regarding `async`, actually it does not necessarily create a thread: you would have to using `std::launch::async` as the first parameter to explicitly ask for a new thread, if you do not use it, then the runtime will choose whether to create a thread or not. A good runtime is likely to maintain its own pool...

Comment: @AlexS: [cont] If you want more precise control over the threads, it is fine too. `async` is only the tip of the iceberg, you are free to dive under the surface and bring up your own thread management policy in its stead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I think in the long term it is probably better to try and get C++11 thread API 'under my belt'. So I'm going to go get it now and switch over from boost.threads before I get any deeper. Cheers.

Comment: Hmmm, After some searching - it appears that currently C++11 is only fully available under VS 2011 for windows??? Or is there some support in VS 2010 express? I'm currently running VS 2008 express. (if you think it is worth it i can post this as a new question)

Comment: @AlexS: That might be true, I must admit I don't use VS but I think their team focused on bringing full multithreading support to VS 2011 so you should have both atomics and threads there. VS 2011 Express if free too, so there is no reason you cannot upgrade your compiler :)

Answer (score 2):

You protected the counter with a mutex, ensuring that no two threads can access the counter at the same time. Your other option would be using [Boost::atomic](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/atomic/usage_examples.html), [c++11 atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) or platform-specific atomic operations.

However, your code seems to access `mCounter` without holding the mutex:

```
    while ( mCounter < mTotal )
```

That's a problem. You need to hold the mutex to access the shared state.

You may prefer to use this idiom:

1. Acquire lock.
2. Do tests and other things to decide whether we need to do work or not.
3. Adjust accounting to reflect the work we've decided to do.
4. Release lock. Do work. Acquire lock.
5. Adjust accounting to reflect the work we've done.
6. Loop back to step 2 unless we're totally done.
7. Release lock.

Comment: good point about mCounter I had taken care of this in the 'real' code, i'll put something in and check out atomic.

Comment: Im sorry, I don't understand the idiom you have posted or more precisely how it differs from what I currently have, in other words I dont see how it avoids incorrectly incrementing the counter.

Comment: @AlexS: The idea is that you isolate the parts of the code that take time (doing actual work, waiting for work) and wrap them in an unlock/lock pair. At all other times, you hold the lock. It inverts the usual pattern of acquiring the lock, doing something quick, and then releasing it to the pattern of releasing the lock, doing something slow, and then re-acquiring it.

Comment: so for example, at point 5 only one thread would do this part due to the lock in point 4?

Comment: Ok, I understand what your suggesting now but when the lock is acquired at 1 and 4 what stops other threads from acquiring it, and i.e. performing 5 again, when it is released? (Sorry being dim - this is outside my comfort zone a little)

Comment: If there's anything you need to do to let other threads know that you're going to do some particular piece of work, you do it at step 3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a message-passing solution. This is more easily enabled by libraries like TBB or PPL. PPL is included for free in Visual Studio 2010 and above, and TBB can be downloaded for free under a FOSS licence from Intel.

```
concurrent_queue<unsigned int> done;
std::vector<Work> work; 
// fill work here
parallel_for(0, work.size(), [&](unsigned int i) {
    processWorkItem(work[i]);
    done.push(i);
});
```

It's lockless and you can have an external thread monitor the `done` variable to see how much, and what, has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to disagree with David on doing multiple lock acquisitions to do the work.

`Mutexes` are expensive and with more threads contending for a `mutex` , it basically falls back to a system call , which results in user space to kernel space context switch along with the with the caller Thread(/s) forced to sleep :Thus a lot of overheads.

So If you are using a multiprocessor system , I would strongly recommend using spin locks instead [1].

So what i would do is :

=> Get rid of the scoped lock acquisition to check the condition.

=> Make your counter volatile to support above

=> In the while loop do the condition check again after acquiring the lock.

```cpp
class someTask {
 public:
 volatile int mCounter; //initialized to 0       : Make your counter Volatile
 int mTotal; //initialized to i.e. 100000
 boost::mutex cntmutex;                

 void process( int thread_id, int numThreads )
 {
    while ( mCounter < mTotal ) //compare without acquiring lock
    {
        // The main task is performed here and is divided 
        // into sub-tasks based on the thread_id and numThreads

        cntmutex.lock();
        //Now compare again to make sure that the condition still holds
        //This would save all those acquisitions and lock release we did just to 
        //check whther the condition was true.
        if(mCounter < mTotal)
        {
             mCounter++;  
        }

        cntmutex.unlock();
    }
 }
};
```

[1]http://www.alexonlinux.com/pthread-mutex-vs-pthread-spinlock

Comment: I dont think this will work, multiple threads will increment mCounter after the work is done. Unless i've missed something???

Comment: It does work ! the lockless comparison avoids overheads and the locked comparison enforces sanity of your increments. Secondly lockless comparison with volatile variable makes sure that all threads look at the same copy of the variable.

Comment: but when one thread unlocks the mutex, another thread is free to lock it and proceed to mCounter++  , ????

Comment: i.e. if there are two threads, and mTotal = 10. The while loop will exit after 5 iterations because on each iteration the mCounter is incremented twice. There should be 10 iterations and mCounter should be 10 when the process has ended.

Comment: it does work . pls try it out. let me know if there is any issue and i'll fix it. thanks

Comment: I tried this out but I cant get it to work, here is the output,I use 2 threads and each prints out the value of the counter mT on each loop. Thread 1 = 0
Thread 2 = 1
Thread 1 = 1
Thread 2 = 2
Thread 1 = 3
Thread 2 = 4
Thread 1 = 5
Thread 2 = 6
Thread 1 = 7
Thread 2 = 8
Thread 1 = 9
Thread 2 = 10
Thread 1 = 11
Thread 2 = 12
Thread 2 = 14

Comment: pls share your  code that you got the above output for ! we can look at it to see what's the issue. I am confident about above approach because i have used it multiple times in a production environment code base.